# Define reusable content --- preferably in the body or else in the header

Tags: macros, content-replication

I am writing a document where name of a person A will appear at multiple places section A. Similarly, name of person B will appear at multiple places in section B, etc.

Is there any way by which just before section A, I can define a variable, say, PersonName, assign a value relevant to Person A to it, and use it in section A. Then, redefine PersonName at the beginnig of section B, use it in section B, etc.

If PersonName can not be defined in the body, can I declare it in the preamble and keep assigning different values to it in the body?

Comment: Have a look at `\newcommand` as defined by the LaTeX-Kernel.
`\newcommand{\persona}{Persona Alite}` and \newcommand{\personb}{Persona Belite}.
Or `\newcommand{\person}{alite} \renewcommand{\person}{belite}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is exactly what macros are for. You can define your own macros with `\newcommand{\command}{<actions>}`, and redefine them with `\renewcommand`. Both commands can be given anywhere in the document, so you could do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Section A}
\newcommand{\PersonName}{Person A}
Some text written by \PersonName.

\section{Section B}
\renewcommand{\PersonName}{Person B}
Some text written by \PersonName.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there an equivalent of `\newcommand` in the document body? So that it's just local, like how you might use `{\bf yada yada}`?

Comment: This should be a separate question, but has probably been answered here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105684/limit-macro-newcommand-scope-to-section

Answer (score 0):

With the [`scontents`](https://ctan.org/pkg/scontents) package it's easy enough to do what you're looking for. All stored in memory, of course, if you prefer external files, you can use environment version an the key `write-env=file.tex` and besides storing them in memory, you can have the content in separate files and then use `\input`. I prefer to save in memory :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scontents}
\setupsc{store-cmd=person}
\Scontents{Person A}
\Scontents{Person B}
\begin{document}
\section{Section A}
Some text written by \getstored[1]{person}

\section{Section B}
Some text written by \getstored[2]{person}
\end{document}
```